# Subscriber topic field

Tags: ros, subscribe, rostopic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, to optimize cpu cost, I would like subscribe to a field of topic. Although it is not the exact case, the problem is subscribe to topic type sensor_msgs Temperature containing a header field. It is posible? I'm try with rostopic echo and run but with rostopic info thows a non-existent topic.

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/219167/subscriber-topic-field/) by [Edmodi](https://answers.ros.org/users/14091/edmodi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2015-10-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No, you cannot subscribe to a single field in a message.

> Although it is not the exact case, the problem is subscribe to topic type sensor_msgs Temperature containing a header field.

I don't really understand what you are trying to say. Perhaps if you describe it more clearly, we can help come up with some alternatives.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-10-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Edmodi](https://answers.ros.org/users/14091/edmodi/) on 2015-10-16**:
I wanna to say that my message type was more complex so to explaint my questions I have given the Temperature type as example. Thansk for your answers

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-10-18**:
Well, in any case: you cannot subscribe to a single field. If this is a custom msg, you could always consider splitting it up into multiple messages (and synchronise later if required, using the timestamp).

**Comment by [Edmodi](https://answers.ros.org/users/14091/edmodi/) on 2015-10-19**:
Ok, I will do it. Thanks